# $[0,1]$ is topologically same as $[-1,1]$ mean?

Tags: general-topology, functions, algebraic-topology

I am just getting started with topology. What does $[0,1]$ topologically same as $[-1,1]$ mean?

Any geometric intuition would be great!

Comment: Try $f(x)=2x-1$ which has many properties including continuity and order

Comment: Thank you @Henry. I feel so silly now lol. What do you mean by order?

Comment: Look for the graph of tangent and the graph of a linear function. What will be the graph of the composition?

Comment: I think you'd have trouble finding any property that one has and not the other (besides of course $-1\in [-1,1]$)

Comment: In fact, every closed interval is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.  Try to find a function for an arbitrary $[a,b]$.

Comment: Yup I get it now. $f : [a,b] \mapsto [0,1]$ defined as $f(x) = \frac{x-a}{b-a}$

Comment: T.Harish By order, I mean $x < y \implies f(x) < f(y)$

Comment: I still don't understand the meaning though? I have edited the question. All I understand is $f : [0,1] \mapsto [a,b]$ defined as $f(x) = (b-a)x + a$. Other than a bijective function what is the geometric intuition when they say topologically same as?

Comment: It is a bijective function that is continuous and also has a continuous inverse. This is called a "Homeomorphism" between the set $[0,1]$ and $[-1,1]$. Roughly, this means that the two sets or spaces can be continuously deformed (like the donut-coffee cup metaphor) into each other. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism

Comment: It means everything I can say or do to $[0,1]$ about whether sets are open or closed or near or far I can say about $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just stretch the interval $[0,1]$ to make it into $[-1,1]$ in a continuous way, formally you can do it with a linear map, like $x \to 2x-1$, which has a continuous inverse too. In fact, all closed intervals $[a,b]$ are the same, in the sense that one can be transformed to another and back. Topologically it's the only connected, locally connected compact Hausdorff space $X$ with a countable base such that $X\setminus \{x\}$ is disconnected, except for two points $x$ (the endpoints).